# At which level is Compiler Optimization applied?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction

My question is at which level compiler applies optimization. Is it at the level of different code files? If that is the case then isn't it more inefficient than say if it were applied across the whole code? Secondly, what happens when one of the source file was compiled with no optimization and then linked with one with -O3 level optimization?

I am especially interested in knowing how gcc handle such things.

Comment: Read the [compiler optimization article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Compiler_optimization) on Wikipedia. As you can see, optimization is applied at several stages.

Comment: This is LLVM not GCC, but you'll find it a very interesting read, I promise. http://www.aosabook.org/en/llvm.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Individual translation units can be compiled with separate optimization flags, that's generally not a problem. Compile-time optimizations usually only affect the visible code within one TU.

An exception to that rule is the flag `-fwhole-program`, which indicates that your source code constitutes the entire program and allows for more aggressive optimization:

```
gcc -o prog *.c -O3 -fwhole-program -s
```

That said, GCC has recently introduced another layer of optimisations at *link* time; to use this, compile everything with `-flto` (GCC 4.6). However, this is also independent of the optimization flags for each TU:

```
gcc -c module1.c -flto -O2
gcc -c module2.c -flto -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing
gcc -c module3.c -flto -O0
gcc -c module4.c -O1
gcc -o prog module*.o -flto -s
```

Finally, you can also specify an independent `-O*` option at link stage, but I don't know if that makes any difference.

Also note that precompiled header files cannot be independently optmizied; a PCH is only eligible if it was compiled with the same optimization settings as the TU.

Comment: Can I inline functions which are in an object file, that is, whose code I don't have access to?

Comment: No, inlining can only happen at the compile stage, and the inlined function definition must be visible. That's why you traditionally put inlined functions in the header files.

Comment: Inlining can happen whenever calling and called code are both visible to a program capable of (and allowed to) try optimizing. With LTO (don't know if this is true for today's GCC in particular, but it's definitely true for LLVM), optimizations like inlining can still happen right before linking/naitve code generation (long after the frontend is done). But again, the called code has to be available in some form (obviously ).

Comment: Yeah, LTO adds some new possibilites. Not sure if it's genuine "inlining", I thought it's mainly static duplicate removal. But I don't know LTO very well.

Comment: Again, I can't speak for GCC's LTO passes, but LLVM definitely sees C/C++-level functions and can do all the usual optimizations with them, e.g. "genuine " function inlining and also very clever ones like loop invariant code motion. In fact, nearly all of Clang's optimizations (save perhaps some shortcuts in code generation requring language-specific knowledge) are frontend-independent passes over LLVM IR, the equivalent to object code (nearly as low-level and converted to machine code at the end). And yet it's usually no worse than 10% slower than GCC, often better.

Comment: @delnan: Cool, that's interesting. (The OP's tag was "GCC", but no worries, it's good to expand.) I always thought that Clang was generally not optimizing nearly as well as GCC, but it may well have advantages coming from the IL stage. After all GCC's LTO is done with some intermediate bytecode (I think it's called "gimple").